# How to include javascript file into html file in maven project

Tags: javascript, java, html, maven

I am working on a web development project and I'm having trouble including my javascript files into my html in my Maven project.

I'm on a Mac and I'm using Atom to write my code and when it comes times to run it, I call `mvn package` and then run the .jar file with `java -jar target/xxx.java` all from terminal.

Currently, my folder structure looks like this:

```
Project
  src
    main
      java
        Server.java
      webapp
        resources
          html
            index.html
          js
            index.js
```

Server.java can access the files in the html folder no problem. The issue is when I try including index.js into index.html by doing:

```
<head>
  <script src="js/index.js"></script>
</head>
```

I get this when I go to the webpage:

```
"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at index.js:1:1)"
```

I have tried MANY different paths for the script and I have tried moving the folders around (a lot of resources online with conflicting answers, none of which worked for me). What is the proper folder structure that will allow my java files to access the html files and allow the html files to access the javascript files (as well as css files later).

Thank you in advance!

EDIT:

Here's the javascript file

```
function validateRegistration(){
  console.log("Here");
  return false;
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  document.getElementById("register").addEventListener("submit", validateRegistration());
});
```

Comment: How do you serve the js file?

Comment: Your code says `<script src="js/login.js"></script>` but I do not see any login.js in your file structure. Did you mean to say `<script src="js/index.js"></script>` ?

Comment: Could you show the `.js` file?

Comment: @WOWOW I've added the contents of the .js file at the bottom

Comment: Shouldn't the src attribute be "../js/index.js"?

Comment: @forty-two Unfortunately that doesn't work either. I think it has something to do with how maven packages the files

Comment: You do not need the </script> termination tag when calling a file name of scripts in html and with XHTML neither, just the XML empty element terminator syntax   <script src="../js/login.js" /> , in all common sense though the js directory should be in the html folder the way you have written the path in your code.

Comment: There are other minor problems there perhaps, I hope you do not use cookies with your login. Servers tend to treat folders of the same level as different domains, just like j2ee servers and appContext, whereas if you put the js folder in with the html pages in the html folder the js will be treated as a sub domain of the html in a security context.

Comment: Also, script and folders access could be set too high by domain point.  NB if you read your server documentation you should find there are hundreds more settings that can be placed (extended) into server configuration, some of these security treatment of types of files and folders archives e.t.c. , so generally only one standard way works for a one size fits all scenario, that would be puting the js folder in the html folder.

Comment: A small hint about Atom because Atom has been abandoned (https://github.blog/2022-06-08-sunsetting-atom/) ... I recommend to start learning to use a real IDE like IntelliJ or Eclipse or NetBeans...

Comment: It's not your java files that includes the java script fie. It's the client (browser) that issues a HTTP GET request for that file relative to the URL that returned the HTML. Maybe you should create a proper webapp and deploy into an application server as a war file. https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/usage.html